# Should Refresh Tokens in JWT Authentication Schemes be Signed with a Different Secret than the Access Token?

Tags: security, authentication, jwt, token

I have a very simple question that is essentially as stated in the title.

**When implementing a JWT authentication scheme that incorporates short-lived access tokens and longer term refresh tokens, should these two token types be signed with different secrets?**

I have been learning more about this authentication scheme recently and in my reading I didn't come across a strong opinion or conclusive answer to this question. Some brief Googling and searching Stack Overflow didn't produce any meaningful answers either.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: This is a good question that made me think for a longer while. I have also asked on crypto forum, if there is a limit to how many tokens may be signed with the same secret, as it also may be relevant for this discussion: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/82090/how-many-jwt-tokens-may-be-securely-generated-with-one-secret

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Answer:** No

**Why?**

2 tokens we're speaking of are

1. access token
2. refresh token

Cryptographically there is no upper-bound on key-usage that I'm aware of for either HMAC, RSA or ECDSA. So signing with the same key is totally reasonable to protect from [existential forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature_forgery).

However, if your access-token and refresh-token issuing endpoints are on separate servers, from a key-management security perspective you may wish to sign with different secrets to contain a compromise of one of the two secrets.

Comment: I am accepting this answer because I feel that it most directly addresses the immediate question, but encourage anyone viewing this in the future to also see Marek Puchalski's answer as well since it proposes another important point and a good view. Thank you both for your answers!

Answer (score 15):

My intuition tells me to separate the secrets for the two tokens. But not because of security reasons. I mean, if on of the secrets leaks then you are done. And the attack surface is IMHO the same if there is one secret or two.

The reason for me to keep the secrets apart would be usability and error prevention. Developers sometimes tend to do stupid things, like mixing stuff. One day the developer will try to send a refresh token in place of an access token. If the secrets are different - the token will be simply rejected. If the secrets are the same - what happens next is beyond my imagination (so I would like to prevent this).

Comment: This is pretty deep insight. Feeling confident enough with the security practice to look past it and reflect on the user experience is good stuff.

Comment: As mentioned by another comment, however, you could also indicate the type of token (e.g. refresh or access) in the token payload and thus prevent users from submitting access tokens as refresh tokens; all the while, you'd have 1 JWT secret instead of 2. I'm still digging through the security implications of this tho.

Answer (score 8):

From cryptographic aspect I can agree with the accepted answer.

But one thing to think about is, that if you are using the same secret, you should care how you validate the refresh token. If you just check that the JWT is valid, one could send an access token as the refresh token and obtain a new access token from an previous valid access token.

So you should either use different secrets or care that you specify and validate a flag in the JWT body indicating if this is an access or refresh token.

Comment: I was considering the flag option (i.e. adding some metadata to indicate the token purpose such as if it's an access/refresh token); this would prevent needing multiple JWT secrets, especially if an application employs multiple token authentication methods. The one concern I have is the security implications of leaking the token purpose.

Comment: I don't think that hiding the the token purpose (type) adds anything to security.
If someone is able to get hands on this tokens, there are other much more severe problems than anybody could deduce the token purpose.

Also, an attacker could forge the purpose by sending it to both Endpoints to learn the purpose of the token.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are cases where, for example, you may be using HMACSHA512 to generate signing credentials for the access token, but the encryption algorithm over the refresh token is AES 256 (AES doesn't support 512-bit block sizes), so the keys have to be different.